# Will microwaves interfere with data transfered through fiber optics?

Tags: magnetic-fields, fiber-optics

Do fiber optical cables used for broadband signals of Internet get any interference due to any nearby microwaves generated in mobile phones?

I learned that fiber optics are used to transmit data in the form of light at different frequencies, does nearby microwave interfere with those light passing through the cable?

Comment: Not likely, unless you are talking about literally frying that fiber bundle in a microwave oven or operating right next to an airport radar antenna where fields can be so high that they change materials that are not designed to withstand them. For anything other scenario I would doubt that there will be a measurable impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the signal will not (usually) be corrupted by outside electromagnetic radiation.

[Classical electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) tells us that electromagnetic waves interact [linearly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). Therefore, when microwaves emitted from a nearby tower pass through the fiber, they will interfere with the signal *locally*, but as the waves pass through each other, they will come out on the other side looking exactly like they did before they ever interacted.

Comment: +1 for linearity - although strictly speaking the answer is "yes" as 'interference' _does_ occur (but only at their intersection). Note that the _transceivers_ (the things that convert electrical signal to light and back again) _are_ susceptible to potential interference although they are in practice well shielded. Similarly, it is possible for cables to pick up RF which can interfere with operation (even for shielded, twisted pair cables.) - but most likely only with field strengths that are orders of magnitude greater than found in cell phone transmission.

Answer (score 3):

No interference can occur as the cable is electrically non-conductive.
Source [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber)

> Immunity to electromagnetic interference
>
> Light transmission through optical fibers is unaffected by other electromagnetic radiation nearby. The optical fiber is electrically non-conductive, so it does not act as an antenna to pick up electromagnetic signals. Information traveling inside the optical fiber is immune to electromagnetic interference, even electromagnetic pulses generated by nuclear devices.

Comment: on a lighter note, due to leak from ovens(not a perfect faraday cage i think) , interference can occur between WiFi and microwaves and cause internet problems XD . Ethernet cables for life !

Comment: Alternative, if the microwave field is intense enough to affect the materials in the optical fibre cable you are already in serious trouble and losing the Net connection will be the least of your worries!